# How to get the product gallery images in woocommerce rest api?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know how to get the product gallery images that we add in a woocommerce product from the Woocommerce REST API.

i have gone through the documentation :

> http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#view-a-product

But that no where explains where I can get these.

If there is no way to get these, is there a way to extend the REST API. If yes, then how?

Comment: try this do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );

Comment: Hi Vrajesh, thanks for your help. but, I need it on the rest api, not on the theme

Answer (score 0):

In the link, under Product Properties there appears to be:

> `images`   array   List of products images. See Images Properties

That sounds like what you need.

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking, yes thats the one but it does not return the gallery images, it only returns the featured image.

Comment: Sorry. Since it said it returned an `array` of images I assumed that i meant all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This small snippet helped me a lot:

```
$image_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
array_push($image_ids, $product->get_image_id() );
            
foreach($image_ids as $image_id){
 $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($image_id);
 // Do something with the image URL
}
```

`$product` is a [WC_Product](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html)